# Can I compile mpich 3 with gcc 4.9 on Mavericks?

Tags: macos, performance, gcc

I am trying to compile mpich 3 on a Mac Pro with Mavericks using gcc 4.9. Has any one had luck doing this?

My machine is hanging on configure step.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, luck was had!

Why not install homebrew and let that handle the compiling for you?

That would be the easiest way to install mpich.

If you insist on compiling manually, you would have to provide information on *where* the configure programs hangs. I.e. what is the output of the program (take a look in the configure log).